# C Wire in HVAC Unit

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, wire

I am looking to install a new style thermostat in my apartment and it requires a C wire.

I do have an extra wire run from my HVAC unit to where my thermostat is. But when tracing it back to my HVAC unit it is not plugged into anything.

So I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out where to put it in the HVAC unit to use as a C wire.

Here are two picture of what I am looking at. I wish it was as easy as plugging wires into a circuit board but it seems my system is a little out of date in that regard.

Any help is much appreciated! I can post more pictures if needed.

Update 2:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have a wiring diagram on your system that you can post a picture of?

Comment: I do not. Is it impossible to figure out without it?

Comment: Can you take a photo of your 24V transformer then?

Comment: Okay I updated it with what I believe you are asking for..hopefully it is good enough quality

Comment: Hrm...it seems your transformer is mounted quite awkwardly...can you get a better photo of how it's hooked up?

Comment: This is about the best I can get with the angle..not a lot of room to work with

Comment: Those are great artsy photos, but not very useful for helping you solve your problem.

Comment: What's the make and model of the unit?

Comment: Yeah I know..good quality but not helping my case :(

The furnace is: Trane BLU055E924B1